# Save image path to BD - Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I am making a form in laravel 5.8 in which I am trying to save the image in a folder and the path in the database.
But just save the image and not the route, I've been searching and haven't found a solution.

The "uploads" folder (folder where images are saved) is located inside the "public" folder.

This is my controller:

```
public function store(SaveAssistanceRequest $request)
{

    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
        $file = $request->file('photo');
        $name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $name);
    }

    $assistance= new Assistance();
    $assistance->photo =  $name;

    Assistance::create($request->validated());

    return redirect()->route('assistances.index')->with('status',' Assistance was created successfully.
```

');
    }

This file validates the data

```
class SaveAssistanceRequest extends FormRequest
```

{

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'resident_id' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required',
        'entry_time' => 'required',
        'departure_time' => 'required',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return[
        'resident_id.required' => 'Assistance needs a resident',
        'date.required' => 'Assistance needs a date',
        'entry_time.required' => 'Assistance needs one hour of entry',
        'departure_time.required' => 'Assistance needs a departure time',

    ];
}
```

}

Can anybody help me?

Comment: where is the validated(), you called $request->validated

Comment: I updated my question with the file that validates the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function store(SaveAssistanceRequest $request)
{
$name='';

if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    $file = $request->file('photo');
    $name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $name);
}

$assistance=Assistance::create($request->validated());
$assistance->photo =  $name;
$assistance->save();

return redirect()->route('assistances.index')->with('status',' Assistance was created successfully.
```

Comment: Thanks, save the route!

Comment: ok, i just edited it, you can also try the edited one if you have errors